# Uniformly continuity VS Continuity.

Tags: real-analysis

The function $f,g : (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ satifies the $(1)$ & $(2)$. Show  $\exists \lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$

$(1)$  $\exists \lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} g(x)$

$(2)$ $\forall a,b \in (0,\infty)  $, $\vert f(b) - f(a) \vert \leq \vert g(b) - g(a)\vert $

---

Here is my attempt.

Say $\exists \lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} g(x) = L$. Then  $\exists \delta>0$ $s.t.$ $0 <x <\delta  \Rightarrow \vert g(x) -L \vert < {\epsilon \over 2}$

Consider $0 <x,y  <\delta $ Then, $\vert g(x)-g(y)\vert \leq \vert g(x)-L \vert +  \vert g(y)-L \vert < \epsilon$

Hence By $(2)$, $\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \leq \vert g(x) - g(y)\vert < \epsilon $.

I concluded the $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0, \delta)$. Therefore, $\exists \lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$

But In my study group, my colleague pointed out what I've mistaken. He said, "$\delta $ is depend on the $\epsilon$. So this is not definition of the uniformly continuity."
And he suggested the definition of the uniformly continuity and continuity(or the limits.) He claimed "When the uniformly continuity case, $\delta$ is not depend on the $\epsilon$." based on the $(4)$

$(3)$ Defintiion of the Continuity on $(a,b)$ : " $\forall \epsilon > 0,\; { \forall x,y\in (a,b)} \exists \delta>0 \;\; : \lvert x - y\rvert< \delta \Rightarrow \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert <\epsilon$"

$(4)$ Definiton of the Uniformly continuity on $(a,b)$ : "$
\forall \epsilon > 0,\;{\exists \delta>0 \; \forall x,y\in (a,b)} \; : \lvert x - y\rvert< \delta \Rightarrow \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert <\epsilon$"

Unlike his thought, lots of the exercise in the textbook, first case related with the $(3)$(or the proving the existence of the limits) We usually find $\delta = \delta(x,\epsilon)$ depending on the two variables $x$ and $\epsilon$.(When the limit case
$0 < \vert x -y \vert < \delta $ ). Plus on the other hand, the case related with the $(4)$, We usually find the $\delta =\delta(\epsilon)$ by depending on the $\epsilon$. To more clarify my question let me take a simple example.

$e.g.)$ Show $f(x) = x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $D = [0,2]$

When we taking the $\delta= {\epsilon \over 4}$, Then, $\exists \delta= {\epsilon \over 4}$ $s.t.$ $\vert x-y \vert < \delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $\vert f (x) -f(y) \vert = \vert x-y \vert \vert x+y \vert < {\epsilon \over 4}$.

So In my opinion the $\delta$ should be depend on the $\epsilon$ considering  definition of the uniformly continuity.  In my thought, I  can't totally understand my colleague's claim and which point I was wrong.

Please help me to find my error in my solution. Plus Is his claim right? And why does it hold?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say

> Say $\exists \lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} g(x) = L$. Then  $\exists \delta>0$ $s.t.$ $0 <x <\delta  \Rightarrow \vert g(x) -L \vert < {\epsilon \over 2}$

But you haven't define how $\epsilon$ is picked up. Your colleague is right. implicitly, you have selected $\epsilon$. It would be much better to state it explicitly: *for $\epsilon >0$...*

Then as you colleague mentioned, the $\delta$ defined above depends on the $\epsilon$. So at the end, you have not proved uniform continuity. You have just prove that for an $\epsilon$ that you select, you have an interval $(0,\delta_\epsilon)$ for which you have $$\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \leq \vert g(x) - g(y)\vert < \epsilon $$ for $x,y \in (0,\delta_\epsilon)$.

The issue is that as $\epsilon$ decreases, $\delta_\epsilon$ may also decrease. At the end, the inequalities will only be valid for all $\epsilon$ in an empty interval... which doesn't have an interest.

Comment: ah thanks for your answer. But the Should the delta does depend on the epsilon according to the definition?  We usually find the $\delta(\epsilon)$ to show the uniformly continuity. Hence under the condition taking the epsilon for limit for $g(x)$, then automatically $\forall x,y \in \delta(\epsilon) \Rightarrow \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert <\epsilon$(i.e uniformly continuity) I thought. But  If the exact meaing of the U.C  is  delta doesn't depend on the epsilon, what is the meaning of $\delta(\epsilon)$ to show uniformly continuity? (The example $x^2$ above etc.)I'm really confused.

Comment: Ah there was typo.  I meant $\forall x,y \in (0, \delta(\epsilon)) \Rightarrow \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert < \epsilon$